# Unable to stop subprocess fully in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script to run a few subprocesses, unfortunately, when I tried to kill the subprocess, it doesn't really end and it still runs in the background. This the python code that I start my subprocess with.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', "python3", "networkLogScript.py"],preexec_fn=os.setsid)
px = subprocess.Popen(["python", "testingLog.py"], preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

This is how I try to kill the processes:

```
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid),signal.SIGTERM)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(px.pid),signal.SIGTERM)
p.terminate()
px.terminate()
p.kill()
px.kill()
```

Sadly, this did not kill the process and it is still running. Would really appreciate any help! Thank you :)

Comment: Is it only happening when having more than one process ?

Comment: probably you will have to do cleanup with atexit or win32api(windows)

Comment: Did the `sudo` run without a password or `askpass`?  If it did then the `python3` could be running under `root`, so an ordinary user won't be able to kill it.